# How to display specific row in datagridview from ms access database in VB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

[image]

Hi, I am developing a vb project. I have a MS-access database with  3 coloumns(Itno,Name,Price).
In form i have added two text box and add button (TextBox2=Itno,Textbox=quantity).
if user give's the Itno and quantity and click the add button,then the Name and price of the Itno should be displayed in the datagridview along with the quantity entered  in the Textbox3.

I have tried as for as my knowledge. But i can not able to display the data in Datagridview. Can any one please help me...

Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Imports System.Data.DataTable

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim ad As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim cm As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim co As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dr As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim tb As New DataTable("Table")

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        tb.Columns.Add("Iteam", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        tb.Columns.Add("Quantity", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        tb.Columns.Add("Price", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        DataGridView1.DataSource = tb
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        co = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        co.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
                "Data Source=C:\Users\Vicky\Desktop\db\bill\bill.mdb;"
        Try
            co.Open()
            Dim cd As String
            cd = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE Itno='" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
            cm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(cd, co)
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader()
            While dr.Read()
                Dim n As String
                Dim p As String
                p = dr("Price").ToString
                n = dr("Name").ToString
                tb.Rows.Add(p.ToString, TextBox3.Text, n.ToString)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = tb

            End While
            co.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have provided relevant code, which is good, but you haven't provided any explanation, which is equally important.  Provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of exactly what you're trying to achieve and how the actual behaviour of the code differs from your expectations.  Those who think that "the title says it all" are rarely correct.

Comment: If you want to populate a `DataTable` from a data reader then it's a one-liner: `myDataTable.Load(myDataReader)`.

Comment: If a `DataTable` is already bound to a `DataGrdiView` then there's no reason to bind it again.  If you want to change the data, simply `Clear` the `Rows` collection and then repopulate.  The existing bind will cause the new data to appear in the grid.

Comment: thanks guys can you give the correct piece of code in  my project

Comment: i'm very unclear about this problem

Comment: So, are you saying that what you actually want is to be able to add new rows to the grid from the `TextBoxes`?  The code you have makes it look like you want to use the `TextBoxes` to specify which existing rows to get from the database.  If you can't actually tell us clearly what you want then we aren't going to magically be able to tell you how to do.  I can understand that you may be unclear on how to achieve what you want but how can you possibly be unclear on how you want the application to behave?

Comment: yes i want the existing row to be displayed in gridview  by using textbox to specify the row which i needed

Comment: So why are you adding `TextBox3.Text` to the `DataTable` manually? Are you evar actually going to provide a proper explanation or am I just going to get sick of wasting my time asking you things that you should have already explained and give up.  Stop, think, explain.

Comment: Given your Exception I think that the first problem is in your query, you are comparing a number with a string: `WHERE Itno='" & TextBox2.Text & "'` (note the `'`).
Another note, with your query you are exposed to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and you are not correctly disposing your objects (like the connection)

Comment: Wow...u r the man it worked!!! Thanks jmcilhinney & Matteo Umili

Comment: U guys r the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Dim cd As String
        cd = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE Itno=" & TextBox2.Text & ""
        cm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(cd, co)
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read()
            Dim n As String
            Dim p As String
            p = dr("Price").ToString
            n = dr("Name").ToString
            Dim R As DataRow = tb.NewRow
            R("Name") = n.ToString
            R("Quantity") = TextBox3.Text
            R("Price") = p.ToString
            tb.Rows.Add(R)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = tb
```

i have corrected the code